# Deploying cakephp 1.3.10 to IIS7 but not working

Tags: cakephp, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am tying to get a cake project working on iis but will little luck. I am using cakephp 1.3.10 and IIS7 with url filters installed. I have tried the cake book web.config but no luck with that and also tried importing the filters into iis but that also did not work. So i am trying to just use cake with no pretty urls but i still cannot get it to even load a test controller all it does it just present 500 errors. I have no idea what the hell is going on. Any help would be appreciated.

My current status is having removed the .htaccess files and the web.config as well, using the docroot as the parent director above app, cake etc and trying to access a controller with :

http://the.url/index.php/controller/index

Comment: See the error logs for possible explanation. Does this simple php file work? `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: In my machine (win 2008), cakephp and iis7 are working fine with web.config ( http://book.cakephp.org/view/1636/URL-Rewrites-on-IIS7-Windows-hosts). BTW, you need to install URL rewrite module, not url filters. Are you trying to do different things?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem might be due to extensionless urls.

Try the article I wrote about it here:

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/vanremortele/2011/05/08/cakephp_rewrites_on_windows_server_net_framework_4_0_extensionless_urls_fix